# Покупка/обмен репутации

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Давно слышал, что хотели такое сделать. Тем, кто хочет ответов - покупка, тем кто отвечает, соответственно,- деньги.

Кто в курсе данной темы!?

Answer (score 8):

Портал stackoverflow.com основан на помощи в решении любых задач, будь то астрофизика, психология или программирование.

Вся помощь производится на бесплатной основе. Если простым языком, то люди просто стараются помочь тем, у кого возникают конкретные проблемы.
Здесь не решают задачи за людей, и это не портал по выполнению проектов на платной основе.

Основная суть заключается в том, что Вам могут помочь только в том случае, если Вы действительно пытаетесь разобраться в проблеме, стараетесь решить задачу, а не просто вбросить задание на решение тем, кто отвечает на вопросы.

Для выполнения задач есть другие порталы в интернете, и Вы их можете найти самостоятельно.
Что касается людей на `stackoverflow`, то здесь, по большей своей части находятся высококвалифицированные люди в своей сфере. Подобные люди никогда не остаются без работы.
Если же Вам лень писать каждый вопрос отдельно, или Вы совершенно не понимаете как справиться с задачей, или хотите, чтобы кто-то выполнил за Вас Вашу работу, то Вы можете пригласить в чат любого специалиста, который на Ваш взгляд действительно разбирается в конкретном вопросе и предложить ему оплату. 
Так же Вы можете создать чат и постараться привлечь туда необходимых специалистов.
А то что предлагаете Вы - превратит `stackoverflow` в портал выполнения услуг, что противоречит изначальной концепции портала.

P.S. здесь программисты помогают другим программистам, который стараются разобраться в конкретной задаче, а не выполняют за них работу.

Comment: `Профессионалы Stackoverflow` сидят на работе и работают работу. А в свободное время заходят на СО, чтобы чем-нибудь помочь. Главная награда - плюсик в карму. Чем больше плюсиков, тем большим людям помог. БЕСПЛАТНО! Просто потому что комьюнити, а не рынок какой-то. Коллегам всегда помочь приятно.